# Assembly function implementation with fallback

Tags: go, assembly

I have a function written on Go that I would like to optimize in assembly. I currently only want to write it for amd64 which is the most frequent target. Assembly for other targets may be added later. By default it should use the Go code.

Unfortunately I didn't manage to achieve this. Looking at the documentation I found online it seam that I have to declare an external function, and provide the assembly for every possible target.

I can provide a Go function with a different name, and then in the assembly code jump to it. This looks tedious and I can't ensure I have provided the assembly file for all possible targets.

Is there a way to provide a Go function, and an alternate version to use instead when compiling for particular targets (e.g. amd64) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard way to do this is to have at least four files, three of which are protected by build constraints, either by use of the `+build` tag or by the filename.

- wrapper.go:

  - Contains function and documentation for a wrapper function which calls the conditionally compiled implementation function
- impl_generic.go

  - Go implementation for non-optimized platforms
- impl_asm.go

  - Function declaration of any assembly implementations
- impl_amd64.s

  - amd64 assembly implementation of your function

wrapper.go

```
package mypkg

import "fmt"

func Wrapper(s string) {
    fmt.Println(impl(s))
}
```

impl_generic.go

```
// +build !amd64

package mypkg

func impl(s string) string {
    // TODO: non-assembly implementation
}
```

impl_asm.go

```
// +build amd64

package mypkg

// defined in *.s

func impl(s string) string
```

impl_amd64.s

```
TEXT ·impl(SB),$0
    // TODO: AMD64 implementation
    RET
```

---

To add an assembly implementation for another architecture:

1. Concat `,!$arch` to the first impl_generic.go build constraint item
2. Add `$arch` to the impl_asm.go build constraint list
3. Write the assembly implementation in `impl_$arch.s`

Comment: Is the wrapper function required ? It seam that we could avoid it and directly provide Impl function in assembly.

Comment: @chmike: I like the wrapper function, as it allows you to have a single copy of the function documentation. Otherwise, both the generic and the impl functions need to have documentation.

Comment: that is a good argument. Is the wrapper removed by inlining ?